# Handling blur on search input with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, focus

I'm currently working on an Instagram clone using React and Styled-Components. Right now I'm getting the navbar in order and trying to emulate the behavior that the desktop Instagram page uses on the search field.

They have multiple `<span>` elements inside of a wrapper in front of the `<input>` when the element is not in focus. When the search field is clicked those elements are replaced with new icons that have no wrapper and the `<input>`'s value is no longer hidden (I'm hiding the input value by setting the `color` equal to the `background-color` when it's not in focus). I've managed to get all of this working on my clone.

My problem is the transition back to an unfocused search field. When I add an `onBlur` event, it triggers when I click on the `<RightSearchIcon/>` ***even if the event is on the `#search-container` instead of the `<input>`***

**Edit for more clarification:**

*On the Instagram page, typing will fill the input field with a new query. If you click outside of the search field the formatting will change back but the new query will be maintained instead of the "Search" placeholder text. This is different from when you click the `XCircle` element, which clears the typed query and replaces it with the default `"Search"` text.
I can maintain the user `input` using a blur event, but that makes the `XCircle`'s `onClick` event not work because the `XCircle` is removed from the page as soon as the `input` field is no longer focused (which occurs before the onClick event can fire).*

[Link to a video demonstrating what I'm talking about](https://vimeo.com/573097562)

---

How do I write an event that will trigger when the user clicks outside of the parent div? I feel like I might be thinking about this the wrong way. Should I declare `isFocused` inside the `NavbarContainer` (which is the parent of `SearchContainer`) and then pass an onClick function down to the `SearchContainer`?

I'm eventually planning on incorporating redux to handle communication with the server. Should I be trying to handle this through redux actions and state?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Spinning my wheels a bit and would definitely benefit from some guidance.

```
const SearchContainer = () => {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState("Search")
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false)
  const inputRef = useRef()

  const handleQueryChange = (e) => {
    setQuery(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
    if(query === "Search"){ setQuery("") };
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }

  const handleXCircleClick = () => {
    setQuery("Search")
    setIsFocused(false)
    inputRef.current.blur()
  }

  const handleOnBlur = (e) => {
    if(query === ""){ setQuery("Search") };
    setIsFocused(false)
  }

  return(
    <Div id="search-container" className="search-container">
      <Input 
        id="search-input" 
        className="search-input" 
        onChange={handleQueryChange} 
        value={query}
        ref={inputRef}
        autoComplete="off"
        style={{color: isFocused ? "#262626" : "#fafafa"}}
      />
      {isFocused ? 
        <>
          <LeftSearchIcon className="bi bi-search" />
          <RightSearchIcon onClick={handleXCircleClick} className="bi bi-x-circle-fill"/>
        </> : 
        <IconWrapper id="icon-wrapper" className="icon-wrapper" onClick={handleOnClick}>
          <SearchIcon className="bi bi-search"/>
          <Span>{query}</Span>
        </IconWrapper>
      }
    </Div>
  )

}
```